# Number of solution of a complex equation with high degree

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am asked to give the number of complex solution of the following equation:

$z^5 = |z|$

I tried to proceed by replacing $|z|^2$  by  $zz^*$
(where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$).
But then the equation becomes:

$z^9=z^*$

I really don't know how to solve either of the equations.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use polar or exponential form.

Answer (score 3):

$$\rho^5e^{i5\theta}=\rho,$$

then $\rho=0$ or

$$\rho^4e^{i5\theta}=1.$$

As the RHS is real, $e^{i5\theta}$ as well and there are five additional solutions,

$$\rho=1,\\\theta=\frac{2k\pi}5.$$

Answer (score 2):

> According to OPs first step we use $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$ and we get
>   \begin{align*}
> z^{10}&=z\overline{z}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We see $z=0$ is a solution. Excluding it from now on we can divide by $z$ and get
>   \begin{align*}
> z^9&=\overline{z}
> \end{align*}

Now we follow the comment to OPs question.

> It's convenient to use polar coordinates and represent $z=re^{i\varphi}$ with $r> 0$ and $0\leq \varphi < 2\pi$. ($r>0$, since we have excluded $z=0$). We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> r^9e^{9i\varphi}&=re^{-i\varphi}\\
> r^8e^{10i\varphi}&=1
> \end{align*}
>   Since $r>0$, $r=1$ follows and we get 
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{10i\varphi}=1
> \end{align*}

The last equation implies since $e^{2k\pi i}=1$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$
\begin{align*}
10i\varphi&=2k\pi i\\
\varphi&=\frac{k}{5}\pi \qquad k=0,2,4,6,8
\end{align*}

*Note:* The selection of $k$ is according to $\arg(z^5)=\arg(|z|)=0$ and we have to respect that $0\leq \varphi < 2\pi$.

$$ $$

> We conclude the number of solutions of the equation $z^5=|z|$ is $6$, with solutions
>   \begin{align*}
> z\in\{0\}\cup\left\{\left.e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{5}}\right|k=0,\ldots,4\right\}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Note that (modulo $2 \pi$) *any* multiple of $\pi/5$ is a solution.

Comment: @vonbrand: I'm sorry, definitely not my day today. But, $z=e^{\frac{\pi i}{5}}$ implies $z^5=-1$ and $|z|=1$?!?

Comment: OK, so they aren't solutions. Perhaps have to point out my mistake/check solutions...

Comment: But in the first step of your resolving the 10i(phi) equation, k is any integer, and in the second step it can only be even... ?

Comment: @Bran: Yes, according to my note  we have to respect, that $\arg{z^5}=\arg{|z|}=0$. I've also added now, that $\varphi < 2\pi$, so we take $k$ only up to $8$.

Comment: @Bran: Please note, we can *avoid* squaring the equation, by simply noting that $|z|=r$. So, the answer from YvesDaoust is more convenient! Maybe you want to check and compare both variations of the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody followed the comment's suggestion, but used the wrong $|z|=zz^\ast$, and when I pointed this out, deleted the answer. Let me do that with the correct $|z|^2=zz^\ast$. The equation becomes, by squaring:

$$z^{10}=zz^\ast.$$

$z=0$ is a solution, so dropping it we can divide by $z$ and we get:

$$z^9=z^\ast,$$

as OP says. Now we follow the suggestion, and set $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$. Substitute that and we get:

$$\rho^9e^{i9\theta}=\rho e^{-i\theta}\iff\rho^8e^{i10\theta}=1.$$

But then we have $\rho^8=1$, or $\rho=\pm1$ but $\rho\geq0$ so $\rho=1$. Then $e^{i10\theta}=1$, which means $\theta=\frac{2\pi+2k\pi}{10}=\frac{\pi}{5}+k\frac{\pi}{5}$, where $k=0,\dotsc,9$.

Then again, without using the expression for $|z|$ we just substitute and get:

$$\rho^5e^{i5\theta}=\rho\iff\rho^4e^{i5\theta}=1.$$

So again $\rho=1$ and $e^{i5\theta}=1$ so $\theta$ is as above. So using $|z|^2=zz^\ast$ yields a longer path in this case.

**Edit**

As the deleter of the now-undeleted A made me notice in comments, squaring the equation adds 5 extra solutions. Only the odd $k$s are actual solutions to the equation, whereas the even $k$s solve the squared equation but not the starting one. Indeed, taking an even $k$ shows an argument of $\frac{\pi+2n\pi}{5}$, which doesn't solve the original equation as that equation needs $e^{i5\theta}=1$, as I showed just above, and such an argument gives $e^{i5\theta}=-1$. Hence, the equation has 5 solutions ($k=0,2,4,6,8$ above) plus the null solution. Let me list them:

$$e^{i(\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac{\pi}{5})},e^{i(\frac{\pi}{5}+3\frac\pi5)},e^{i(\frac\pi5+5\frac\pi5)},e^{i(\frac\pi5+7\frac\pi5)},e^{i(\frac\pi5+9\frac\pi5)},0$$

Or:

$$0,e^{i\frac25\pi},e^{i\frac45\pi},e^{i\frac65\pi},e^{i\frac85\pi},e^{i\frac{10}{5}\pi}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks again for your hint. I've deleted my answer only *temporarily* in order to correct it without interruption. Btw: In the final part of your answer it's not quite clear to me, how many *different* solutions you consider.

Comment: In effect @markusscheuer I haven't pointed out that squaring adds solutions. The starting equation has 5 solutions plus 0, whereas the squared thing has 10 (one for each integer $k$ from 0 to 9) plus zero.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer see the edit.